# How to send email in php with wp_mail

Tags: php, wordpress

I have seen similar code in use all over the place, but I just can't get it to work...

```
$to = 'myeamil@gmail.com';
$subject = 'test';
$message = 'test';
$headers = 'just a test';
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

I also tried with:

```
if (wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message )) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

Nothing gets printed.
What am I missing?

I would prefer not to use a plugin for this.

Comment: I assume you have SMTP setup properly on the server? Or can you confirm that emails come from this same server?

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your script.  blank page may mean PHP encountered a fatal error but the server is in production mode and wont show any.  You can also check the error_log file for any messages.

Comment: your $headers param looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly different from how I have it:

```
try {
    $sent = @wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log('oops: ' . $e->getMessage()); // this line is for testing only!
}

if ( $sent ) {
    error_log('hooray! email sent!'); // so is this one
} else {
    error_log('oh. email not sent.'); // and this one, too
}
```

Oh, and it will **not** work on localhost without proper setup.

Comment: `wp_mail` doesn't throw any exceptions so the try/catch block is unnecessary.

Comment: @drew010 Thanks, had no idea. Glad I posted this!

Comment: It is not a good habbit to use error suppression: Remove the `@`, especially since you have a try-catch block surrounding the `wp_mail` call.